# Error "DataTables warning: table id=alumnos - Cannot reinitialise DataTable"?

Tags: ajax, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy haciendo una tabla de filtrado con *dataTable* y *Ajax* todo me funciona a la perfección puedo ver los registros y filtrar pero siempre que recargo la pagina me sale un *alert* con el mensaje:

> DataTables warning: table id=alumnos - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/3"](http://datatables.net/tn/3%22)

¿Alguien sabe que podría ser?

Aquí les dejo el código que tengo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_ex.css">
<table id="alumnos" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>CI</th>
            <th>Año</th>
            <th>Sección</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> <link rel="" href="../css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css"> <script src="../js/datatables.min.js"></script> <script src="../js/search.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#alumnos').DataTable({
            "ajax":{
                "url": "consulta.php",
                "dataSrc":""
            },
            "columns":[
                {"data": "id"},
                {"data": "apellidos"},
                {"data": "nombres"},
                {"data": "cedula"},
                {"data": "grado"},
                {"data": "seccion"}
            ]  
        });
    });
          
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $('#alumnos').DataTable({
           orderCellsTop: true,
           fixedHeader: true 
        });
        //Creamos una fila en el head de la tabla y lo clonamos para cada columna
        $('#alumnos thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#alumnos thead' );

        $('#alumnos thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
            var title = $(this).text(); //es el nombre de la columna
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por...'+title+'" />' );
     
            $('input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                    table
                        .column(i)
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Estas reinicializando la tabla siendo que esta ya ha sido iniciada. En cambio podías iniciarla una vez, recuperarla o destruirla.  ->https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, esto es porque se está haciendo una doble inicialización. Lo que te recomiendo hacer es poner todas las opciones de customización en la inicializacion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#alumnos').DataTable({
        "ajax":{
            "url": "consulta.php",
            "dataSrc":""
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "apellidos"},
            {"data": "nombres"},
            {"data": "cedula"},
            {"data": "grado"},
            {"data": "seccion"}
        ],  
       orderCellsTop: true,
       fixedHeader: true 
    });
```

...

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono a la perfección